# Linux Redhat kernel source installation?

Tags: centos, linux-kernel

I downloaded my kernel source rpm version, uname -a, from the [ftp.redhat.com](ftp://ftp.redhat.com/) site. When I installed the rpm it put it in `~rpmbuild`. In the past didn't it put it in `/usr/src/redhat`? Did this change? I'm running Centos 6.

Thanks,

--Justin Richard Bleistein

Comment: Why would you expect the kernel to be built in a directory called "redhat" if you are running CentOS? Anyway, what is your question exactly? If you are observing a different behavior to what you are used to then clearly something _has_ changed :). Is this causeing you problems? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

> In the past didn't it put it in `/usr/src/redhat`?

Yes.

> Did this change?

Yes.

Any further questions?

Comment: What did it change to? Why, and is it documented anywhere?

Comment: It isn't. Check the mailing lists.